# BIRT Report processes grid in reverse order in web viewer

Tags: birt

I have a BIRT report with 2 datasets Measure that returns a single row name and a number, and Contracts which returns a contract type and a value.

The report is laid out to show the measure and then the list of contracts and values. I want to do a ratio of the contract value to the measure, the whole thing looking like:

```
MEASURE 1 --- 200

CONTRACT TYPE 1 --- 1000 --- 0.2 
CONTRACT TYPE 2 ---  200 --- 1.0
CONTRACT TYPE 3 ---  400 --- 0.5
```

This is done by setting up a hierarchy in the Report Layout as follows:

```
+ Report Layout
++ Grid
+++ Table (bound to measure data set, has OnRender trigger that sets global variable for measure name and number)
++ Grid
+++ Table (bound to Contract Type data set)
++++ Cell 
+++++ Bound data element with a formula that gets the global variable for the Measure and does the contract value / measure number math
```

This works exactly as expected when I run the report from the previewer in the Eclipse designer.

When I run on the web viewer, all the ratios are blank. 
So I put a logging in the OnRender trigger and the formula to see what the global variables are set to.

When I run in the previewer, I get the following results:

```
-- measure name global variable - Enrollment
-- measure value global variable - 14000
--- contract ratio cal get measure value -- 14000
--- contract ratio cal get measure value -- 14000
--- contract ratio cal get measure value -- 14000
--- (and so on, one for each contract type row returned.)
```

When I run in the web viewer, I get the following results

```
--- contract ratio cal get measure value -- null
--- contract ratio cal get measure value -- null
--- contract ratio cal get measure value -- null
--- (and so on, one for each contract type row returned.
-- measure name global variable - Enrollment
-- measure value global variable - 14000
```

In other words, in the previewer the top of the report grid cell and data set execute first, and in the web viewer, the order is reversed.

What I'm finding says that execution should happen in the order it appears in the Report Layout hierarchy in the designer. Anyone have any idea what I can do?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between a preview and the webviewer is, a preview does not have a specific render step. Technically, a preview is a "RunAndRender" task, when webviewer has two distinct "run" and  "render" tasks. This is why sometimes we can see this kind of differences.

As you describe the issue, it seems this global variable is defined in "onRender" script of your measure datafield, but it is consumed by contracts from "onCreate" "onPrepare", or from an expression of an element.

Anyway to solve the problem you would better set this global variable in onCreate script and make it persistent, to be sure it can be consumed from onRender events. To make a global var persistent there are two options:

**Report variable:** create a report variable in your outline and use it with `vars["myVariable"]`

**old fashion:** use `reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable` and `reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable`

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not a good idea to do calculations in the onRender events.

You should move your code to the onCreate events instead.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the information found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160153/birt-script-behaves-differently-via-web-viewer?rq=1) that discusses the differences between the generation phase and presentation phase in the web viewer, I altered my approach.

I created the global variables in the OnFetch trigger for the dataset, which made them available to include in the data elements placed in the Contract section of my report.

The results now duplicate what was being generated in the previewer.